# Is it necessary for a controller action that only returns a view to be asynchronous?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await

Take this basic action:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Modify it to make use of async/await:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return await Task.Run(() => View());
}
```

I am confused whether this will improve my code or not. From my understanding, the await keyword will release the calling thread so that it may be available for use elsewhere, which is better utilisation of available threads.

But I am not actually doing anything else except this one thing which is returning a view. Having the async keyword actually introduces a state machine within the compiled code, which adds complexity.

Is making this action asynchronous worth it? Is there a better way of modifying it to make it asynchronous?

Comment: You haven't really modified the controller to be asynchronous. All requests are processed by separate threads anyway. `async/await` is meant to avoid blocking those threads when they perform IO work. If you use `await Task.Run()` you just use a new task/thread to do work that could easily be done by the original thread

Comment: `await Task.Run()` is almost always wrong. - `Task.Run()` - "TPL, please find a thread to run this code on whilst I'm busy doing other things". `await` - "I've got no useful work to do on *this* thread - go see if something else can make use of it"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That's only really true in an ASP context.  Which, granted this is, but your statement implies it applies in other contexts where it's very much not true.

Comment: @Servy - it's true in the asp context. It's true in the console context. It can be true in contexts with a "blessed thread" (e.g. the UI thread) if it's running other code which will frequently `await` itself and not tie up the CPU. It's not true if it's CPU bound work that you're trying to push off of the UI thread. But I don't often see it being used in that circumstance.

Comment: It is an artificial question. When you need data to fill a Model then it changes. Making an Action async is profitable when you have some element in it that is doing async I/O.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me that you should revisit Microsoft's TAP document, and get a better grasp of how you can make Task work for you.

In your example:

```
public Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return Task.FromResult(View());
}
```

It is just essentially returning some HTML, Javascript, and CSS, so it would be less than pointless, meaning, when you add Task to a normal function, there is overhead that can become costly.

Now if you had something like this:

```
public Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var users  = DbContext.GetUsersAsync();
    var groups = DbContext.GetGroupsAsync();

     await Task.WhenAll(users,groups);

    var m = new Model(){
     Users = users.Result,
     Groups = groups.Result
    }

    return View(m);
}
```

In this scenario, Task makes sense, you are essentially performing two different I/O functions at the same time, then waiting for all of them to finish before moving on. You are taking the amount of time that it would have taken to process each call individually, and cutting it down by hopefully half ( at the cost of blocking a potential CPU thread for another "web" user to access the same document.)

```
 public Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var users  = await DbContext.GetUsersAsync();
        var groups = await DbContext.GetGroupsAsync();

        var m = new Model(){
         Users = users,
         Groups = groups
        }

        return View(m);
    }
```

In my third example, even though it using Async / Await, it is still running everything one-by-one, so wasting precious Threads.

The only thing that I can recommend is that Task does not scale well with a large user-base, so while developing your web solution, keep in mind the potential future growth of users and lean-back on the usage of Task-based functions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap

Comment: Just wanted to ask why Task does not scale well with a large user-base? Also, what do you mean a large user-base?

Comment: TAP is an excellent paradigm to make a few functions incredibly fast, but people have the habit of abusing it and wrapping everything I/O related with Task, just like some developers wrap every four lines of code with a try-catch, not realizing it all comes at a cost.  Also, when a function has a Task going, and it is consuming several threads, if the CPU(s) are maxed out, they will start to block new users, in lieu of finalizing the tasks in queue, so when you have a million users, and a weak server, it can gas it out rather quickly.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is No. Since there is nothing `async` going on in `View()` there are no places in the execution where the compiler can release the thread to allow for other work to happen on the same thread.

I would say making this particular method async might be (even so slightly) worse for performance, since the compiler will need to modify your code, making what's executed more complex, once you use the `async` keyword.

The only benefit in making it `async` that I can see would be for consistency if you have a lot of other actions that are in fact taking advantage of `async`. If you *really want* to have a `Task<T>`signature for consistency purposes, you could consider:

```
public Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return Task.FromResult(View());
}
```

(Notice no `async` keywords involved and no `Task.Run` spinning up a new task to run)